# Passing factory data from parent controller to isolate scope directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

So, I have a problem with isolating a directive's scope. Before I isolated the scope, it worked fine, pulling the function that got data from a factory, from the parent scope. This directive will be a slider which will need to be able to have multiple instances on a page. For this reason, I needed to isolate the scope. I have tried a few different things and nothing has worked, so I'm guessing I have something else wrong. Here are snippets of my code.
Thank you in advance for your help. :)

**Edited to add:** Scope is now successfully isolated, but functions don't seem to be. When multiple instances of the directive, functions effect each instance, rather than just one.

Controller:

```
    //

    function BaseController ($scope, dataFactory) {

$scope.getMedia = function () {
    dataFactory.getMedia()
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.sliderItems = data.Items;
            $scope.topItems = [];
            $scope.bottomItems = [];

            // divide results of sliderItems into 2 rows 
            // this ensures that first item from EACH ROW disappears
            for (var i=0; i < $scope.sliderItems.length; i++){
                if ((i+2)%2==0) {
                    $scope.topItems.push( $scope.sliderItems[i]);
                }
                else {
                    $scope.bottomItems.push( $scope.sliderItems[i]);
                }
            }
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load ' + error.message;
        });
}
    }angular
.module('bellApp')
.controller('BaseController', BaseController);

//
```

Directive:

```
    function singleSlider() {
return {
    // default is A, no need to asign 
    templateUrl: 'views/single-slider.html',
    scope: {
        slideritems :'='

    },        
    link: function (scope) {

        scope.displayInfo = function (item) {
            scope.itemDetail = item;
            scope.box = true;
        };

        scope.close = function () {
            scope.box = false;
        };

        scope.sSlide = function () {
            //set the appropriate direction
            scope.direction = 1;
            var slider = scope.slideritems;
            //remove first item from slider
            var shift = slider.shift();
            //send removed item to end of slider array
            slider = slider.push(shift);
        };

        scope.sSlideBack = function () {
            //set the appropriate direction
            scope.direction = 0;
            var slider = scope.slideritems;
            //remove last item from slider
            var pop = slider.pop();
            //send to front of array
            slider = slider.splice(0,0,pop);
        };
    }
};
    }angular
.module('bellApp')
.directive('singleSlider', singleSlider);
```

View:

```
    ...
    <body ng-app="bellApp" ng-controller="BaseController">

    <div single-slider media="getMedia()" class="media-slider"></div>
```

...

Comment: Can you create a plunker? What is not working?

Comment: You are invoking getMedia. it should be '<div single-slider media="getMedia" class="media-slider"></div>' On the other hand, I don't see any invocation of the function inside the directives link function.

Comment: dont pass the funtion if u only need the data. invoke your funtion in the controller $scope.getMedia();  and pass the result what u need  $scope.sliderItems ,
            $scope.topItems ,
            $scope.bottomItems   to the isolated directive

Comment: $scope.getMedia has no return statement - isnt this a problem for directive?

Comment: @micha I've tried invoking and also just using media=getMedia. Neither has worked.
 Could you give me an example of how I would pass those result scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function BaseController ($scope, dataFactory) {

$scope.getMedia = function () {
  dataFactory.getMedia()
    .success(function (data) {
        //same like your
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load ' + error.message;
    });

  }
  $scope.getMedia();
}

angular
.module('bellApp')
 .controller('BaseController', BaseController);
```

directive

```
function singleSlider() {
 return {
   // default is A, no need to asign 
   templateUrl: 'views/single-slider.html',
   scope: {
      topitems :'=',
      bottomitems :'='
   },        
   link: function ($scope) {

    $scope.displayInfo = function (item) {
        $scope.itemDetail = item;
        $scope.box = true;
    };

    $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.box = false;
    };


    ... ( shortened for example )
    }
};
} 
angular
.module('bellApp')
.directive('singleSlider', singleSlider);
```

View 
   ...

```
<div single-slider topitems="topItems" bottomitems="bottomItems" class="media-slider"></div>
```

thats all what i can help without see your dataFactory or rest of the directive

**Edit:** or give your directive a controller and do what you did in the controller  for the directive  in the directive controller

```
function singleSlider() {
  return {
  ...
  controller: 'NameOfYourController'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I also realized that inside the directive, the scope is now lowercase, and I need to reflect that on the template. So fixing those two things helped.

One thing though, is that if I try to put two of these directives on the page together, for example:


        <div single-slider slideritems="sliderItems" class="media-slider"></div>
        <div single-slider slideritems="sliderItems" class="media-slider"></div>

 - both sliders move at the same time when clicked, defeating the purpose of isolated scope. :(

I'll post the whole directive for the single slider.

Comment: if my answer helped you , a upvote for my answer will be good